# Plot dataframe with ggplot2 - R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, graph

I am trying the create a graph using the following dataframe. It has 10 observations and 25 variables (one of them - ID - is just an ID column for the different observations

```
'data.frame':    10 obs. of  25 variables:
 $ NDVI_mean   : num  0.0607 0.0552 0.5811 0.7676 0.0328 ...
 $ NDVI_sd     : num  0.0881 0.0298 0.1644 0.0937 0.0292 ...
 $ NDVI_mean.1 : num  0.0211 0.0549 0.1375 0.1207 0.024 ...
 $ NDVI_sd.1   : num  0.0111 0.0195 0.0227 0.0701 0.0197 ...
 $ NDVI_mean.2 : num  0.0703 0.0715 0.6832 0.769 0.0418 ...
 $ NDVI_sd.2   : num  0.0938 0.0298 0.1601 0.0674 0.0402 ...
 $ NDVI_mean.3 : num  0.0636 0.0552 0.6829 0.732 0.0292 ...
 $ NDVI_sd.3   : num  0.0912 0.0222 0.1613 0.1102 0.0355 ...
 $ NDVI_mean.4 : num  0.092 0.0781 0.6947 0.5256 0.056 ...
 $ NDVI_sd.4   : num  0.0879 0.0211 0.158 0.0686 0.0328 ...
 $ NDVI_mean.5 : num  0.1047 0.091 0.4251 0.3573 0.0722 ...
 $ NDVI_sd.5   : num  0.0441 0.013 0.0585 0.0368 0.0156 ...
 $ NDVI_mean.6 : num  0.0547 0.0654 0.5912 0.6098 0.0404 ...
 $ NDVI_sd.6   : num  0.0874 0.0195 0.2143 0.0975 0.0287 ...
 $ NDVI_mean.7 : num  0.1047 0.0882 0.6914 0.6532 0.0689 ...
 $ NDVI_sd.7   : num  0.0843 0.0177 0.1553 0.0653 0.0299 ...
 $ NDVI_mean.8 : num  0.0859 0.071 0.6905 0.6866 0.0556 ...
 $ NDVI_sd.8   : num  0.0809 0.018 0.1624 0.0866 0.0311 ...
 $ NDVI_mean.9 : num  0.0949 0.1204 0.1434 0.2849 0.1231 ...
 $ NDVI_sd.9   : num  0.00951 0.00719 0.01228 0.03483 0.01023 ...
 $ NDVI_mean.10: num  0.0854 0.0752 0.6712 0.7326 0.0628 ...
 $ NDVI_sd.10  : num  0.0789 0.0212 0.1471 0.0951 0.0326 ...
 $ NDVI_mean.11: num  0.0942 0.0986 0.6434 0.7741 0.0899 ...
 $ NDVI_sd.11  : num  0.0735 0.0188 0.1299 0.0765 0.0277 ...
 $ ID          : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

[Image of the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySr0r.png)

I would like to create a graph with the following characteristics:

The X axes should be the different NDVI_mean variables (NDVI_mean - NDVI_mean.1 - NDVI_mean.2 - etc.)

The Y axes should be the values of those variables

+

I would like the graph to contain 10 lines which correspond to the 10 observations

I am completely new with ggplot2. I have manage to create some graphs using this code but it is not what I want

```
ggplot2(NDVIdf)+geom_lines(aes(x=NDVI_mean, y=ID))
```

Edit

Output of dput(NDVIdf)

```
> dput(NDVIdf)
structure(list(NDVI_mean = c(0.0607135413903215, 0.0551773354119158, 
0.58106114381679, 0.767559372904067, 0.0327779986531678, 0.0178615320775541, 
0.242088217197272, 0.20999285277774, 0.0393074640533382, 0.362654323805063
), NDVI_sd = c(0.0881409040764672, 0.0297587817960566, 0.164350402694459, 
0.0937447350009958, 0.0291673504162979, 0.0328954778667684, 0.154674728930805, 
0.143054126101431, 0.0394783704067313, 0.0311605700206721), NDVI_mean.1 = c(0.0210982854397687, 
0.0549092171312182, 0.137518549485032, 0.120670383289592, 0.0240424367577284, 
0.0159096452554129, 0.0672761385275565, 0.0341803495552938, -0.00134448575083377, 
0.016580205828644), NDVI_sd.1 = c(0.0110723260269658, 0.01951851232517, 
0.0227065359549684, 0.0700670943356275, 0.0196608837546022, 0.0121199724795787, 
0.0585473350749026, 0.0227914450038557, 0.0135058392129466, 0.0150912377421709
), NDVI_mean.2 = c(0.0703180934388137, 0.0714783174472453, 0.683213190781725, 
0.769036956136717, 0.0418112830812162, 0.0284743048998433, 0.23348292946483, 
0.235929665998861, 0.0450296798850473, 0.193100322654342), NDVI_sd.2 = c(0.0937618859311873, 
0.0298498793436821, 0.160085159223464, 0.0673810570033997, 0.0402149180186587, 
0.0397066821267195, 0.150683537602667, 0.145471088294412, 0.0437922991992655, 
0.0141486994532874), NDVI_mean.3 = c(0.063601350404069, 0.0551904437586304, 
0.682930851671194, 0.731967082842268, 0.0291583347580934, 0.0193111448443503, 
0.319631300233593, 0.166050320085929, 0.0366014763086276, 0.221872499210234
), NDVI_sd.3 = c(0.0912293427166813, 0.0222453701937956, 0.161322107465979, 
0.110207844254988, 0.0355049011856384, 0.0349930810428516, 0.226276210965238, 
0.140438890801978, 0.0376830428032925, 0.0220584182188743), NDVI_mean.4 = c(0.0919804842383724, 
0.0781265501499422, 0.694671427954745, 0.525632176936541, 0.055980386796576, 
0.0444207693277835, 0.426953378337129, 0.160783372015251, 0.0609390942283722, 
0.280378773041507), NDVI_sd.4 = c(0.0879414801936151, 0.0210552190044792, 
0.158033594194682, 0.0685669288657517, 0.0327713833848639, 0.0354769286383367, 
0.252469606866754, 0.12982572565032, 0.036836867665617, 0.0411465416161875
), NDVI_mean.5 = c(0.104738543138272, 0.0909713368375085, 0.42508525657118, 
0.357320549164012, 0.0721572385527876, 0.0663794698314188, 0.23911562990616, 
0.142111328436142, 0.0838823297267412, 0.251654432686439), NDVI_sd.5 = c(0.0441048632295888, 
0.0130326877444498, 0.0585279766430101, 0.0368348303398042, 0.0155510862094617, 
0.0192137216652464, 0.0585475549304422, 0.0736886597614494, 0.0212806524351524, 
0.0259938407933158), NDVI_mean.6 = c(0.054670992223019, 0.065381296775636, 
0.591168574495215, 0.609806323819807, 0.0403625648315437, 0.00811946347995523, 
0.310916693477462, 0.158498269033413, 0.0443372830506701, 0.371097291211943
), NDVI_sd.6 = c(0.0874297350407085, 0.0195485598323798, 0.214314782421285, 
0.0974716364190341, 0.0286726835375469, 0.0464844141552075, 0.124111018323546, 
0.128024962302557, 0.0389891785245309, 0.0776972260415738), NDVI_mean.7 = c(0.104681150177595, 
0.0882044567680745, 0.691354972003269, 0.65319672247453, 0.0689026139683328, 
0.0564115948034715, 0.345466555679804, 0.189094867024672, 0.0757218905916805, 
0.473698360613464), NDVI_sd.7 = c(0.0842570243914433, 0.0176701260206802, 
0.15529028462675, 0.0653161775993753, 0.0298643217871498, 0.0350802264835342, 
0.179839784256719, 0.123083052319927, 0.0381348337459403, 0.0504351117371588
), NDVI_mean.8 = c(0.08591308296691, 0.0710169977816541, 0.69050244219096, 
0.686550053201553, 0.05559868259279, 0.0386856009179078, 0.385427380396624, 
0.191494000375466, 0.0582605982908748, 0.634092671211804), NDVI_sd.8 = c(0.0809198942299164, 
0.0179761950231585, 0.162375086927031, 0.0865933396475938, 0.0311069109690036, 
0.0341123644056808, 0.221678551331174, 0.123510636808576, 0.0352156193862569, 
0.037441682380018), NDVI_mean.9 = c(0.0948832729278301, 0.120400127877444, 
0.143375746425582, 0.284877572639076, 0.123096886134381, 0.111171634746743, 
0.223262233590715, 0.120538120679937, 0.0971369124338333, 0.233815280325772
), NDVI_sd.9 = c(0.00951402820331221, 0.00718755312976778, 0.0122787887859583, 
0.0348298462083254, 0.0102326571562652, 0.00707392292527096, 
0.047660749828529, 0.0127667426992843, 0.00615732059786784, 0.0341929453840942
), NDVI_mean.10 = c(0.0853653180560701, 0.0751638478379656, 0.671240397847597, 
0.732629951796317, 0.0628200256114987, 0.0389376153602489, 0.261580310922298, 
0.237551383820751, 0.0543488352606212, 0.729810364384283), NDVI_sd.10 = c(0.0788860954632659, 
0.0212295674726634, 0.147125862744127, 0.0951195938807548, 0.0325819971840338, 
0.0313179762667036, 0.149062631594425, 0.123975319460501, 0.0295479331978356, 
0.0347570926406439), NDVI_mean.11 = c(0.0941656718689444, 0.0985743153705462, 
0.643407964040386, 0.774084527469533, 0.0899420980061257, 0.0535166413991826, 
0.303595683796766, 0.245633779631581, 0.0643377575135575, 0.697236179516483
), NDVI_sd.11 = c(0.0735030069394199, 0.0187835191570716, 0.129850840148202, 
0.0764938134743573, 0.0276954256603995, 0.0260888900038652, 0.122217568202193, 
0.0934074608484564, 0.0272831553843282, 0.026010072370012), ID = 1:10), .Names = c("NDVI_mean", 
"NDVI_sd", "NDVI_mean.1", "NDVI_sd.1", "NDVI_mean.2", "NDVI_sd.2", 
"NDVI_mean.3", "NDVI_sd.3", "NDVI_mean.4", "NDVI_sd.4", "NDVI_mean.5", 
"NDVI_sd.5", "NDVI_mean.6", "NDVI_sd.6", "NDVI_mean.7", "NDVI_sd.7", 
"NDVI_mean.8", "NDVI_sd.8", "NDVI_mean.9", "NDVI_sd.9", "NDVI_mean.10", 
"NDVI_sd.10", "NDVI_mean.11", "NDVI_sd.11", "ID"), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please give us the output of `dput(df)` so we can plot your data. Replace `df` with the name of your data frame.

Comment: I have updated the question with the information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is in wide format but `ggplot` requires that you first convert it to long format. That is, you should have one row per observation per measurement. In your case, you should have a dataframe with 12*2*10 rows, and three columns being: observation (1-10), statistic (mean.1, sd.2, ...) and value.

You can use `tidyr`'s `gather` function to easily reformat the data into long format:

```
library(tidyr)

NDVIdf_forplot <- gather(NDVIdf, key = statistic, value = value, -ID)
ggplot(NDVIdf_forplot, aes(x = statistic, y = value) + geom_line()
```

The `gather` function takes two arguments: key and value, that set the column names for the relevant fields in the new long format dataframe. In this case, key is the name given to the new column that encodes the previous column headings (mean, sd, ...) and value to the previous values (0.0607,...).

The expression `-id` tells `gather` not to remove the `ID` column, so each record in the new dataframe is still associated with the correct id. That way you can use it to separate the different lines in the `ggplot` call like this:

```
ggplot(NDVIdf_forplot, aes(x = statistic, y= value, group = ID)) + geom_line()
```

And, if you want to colour the different observations differently and include a legend, you can use the colour aesthetic:

```
ggplot(NDVIdf_forplot, aes(x = statistic, y = value, group = ID, colour = ID)) + 
    geom_line()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I am trying to implement it but it seems the installation of the package tidyr is not working. I have also tried to install tidyverse but an error message is shown at the end

Comment: I can't help with that without any context. It's probably worth opening another question if you can't find the solution here already. That said, you can achieve the same effect with `reshape2`'s `melt` function if you can install that.

Comment: Hi @Eumenedies, I have a very similar problem to the one posted in this question. The only different is that I can't manage to properly arrange my data. Could you please have a look?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47179207/arrange-dataframe-format-for-ggplot-r

ps: did not want to edit this question since it would be too long and the new answer could be helpful for others